# Google images redirects to some page with random images

Tags: google, url-redirection

My customer have some photos on images.google.com that when clicked redirects to some pages and then stops on http://imageol.com/"something" with one random image.

First I thought that it was a virus, but then I've checked on my machine in our offices and we got the same result.

When I click to go to the website which contains the image the browser follows this path:

```
images.google.com -> yesshare.com -> http://hidereferrer.net/"something" -> http://assigntraffic.com/gateway.php?group=7&source=yesshare.com&referrer= -> http://imageol.com/image/"something"
```

My customer asked to remove these images from google, since sometimes they redirect to pornographic photos and so on, and of course is bad for their business.

I've thought of many possible ways that how this could had happened but my question now is:

What can I do to remove this "images","redirects" from the google search?

Report to google?

And how to prevent to happen again?

PS: English is not my native language, sorry for any mistakes and feel free to correct me.

Comment: Depends why this is happening. My first guess would be some form of malware or browser plugin. If everyone has it, that's not ruled out, but perhaps it is more likely that your router was compromised. Another option is the ISP itself is injecting spam. Figure out who/what is responsible, then you can worry about handling it.

Comment: I've tried it with Firefox, Chrome and Edge and got the same results in all of them. About the router, the customer is using his own network. And why would the ISP do such thing?

Comment: this is cloaking, check the files on the server for injected code

Comment: what happens if you open the image url directly instead clicking them on Google? Try to do right-click - save url - paste in new window and add view-source: before the URL and copy the original URL from there

Comment: It is possible someone just stole the images and is using it on their site in such a way that it gets picked up by Google's spider.

Comment: You have not provided us with enough information to answer your question. Also, this question seems more appropriate for Google than this site.